# Why isn't this regex working in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have this in my script and I am not really sure why it isn't working. It works on a regex tester and it's quite a simple regular expression.

```
var page = '<div id="loginOverlay" class="loginOverlay">' +
 '<div id="loginForm">' +
      '<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/test.jspx" onsubmit="grayLoginAnonymous();return false;" style="margin:0px;" autocomplete="off"><input type="hidden" name="org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN" value="21a9e5a4197cfaefec409d8473f29a6e" />'+    
     ' </form>'+
  ' </div> '+
' </div>';

var pattern = /<input type='hidden' name='org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN' value='((\d|\w)+)' \/>/;
var match = page.match(pattern);
document.write(match);
console.log(page);
console.log(match);

</script>
```

match returns 'null'.
Can someone point out the problem?

Comment: I think it's because you are trying to match that pattern exactly, when var page contains characters before and after that pattern. Try putting a .* at the beginning and end. You may also need to specify matching across new lines.

Comment: Be aware that `.` means "any character" in regular expressions. So while it will also match a literal dot, you should be more specific and write `\.` if you want a regex to match an actual dot.

Comment: It was just a mistake on my part about the double quote and single quote. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used single quotes instead of double quotes. Change the pattern to this and it will work:

```
var pattern = /<input type="hidden" name="org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN" value="((\d|\w)+)" \/>/;
```

Also, make sure to take care of the dots like Tim Pietzcker pointed out in his comment!

Comment: oh. my. god. what a dumb mistake. Thanks Jakob.